# How to find an item in a list (without using "in" method)?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, search

I am trying to find an item in a list without using "in" method. I tried to do it using loop. The code executed successfully, but giving collective result for both (item found as well as item not found). I tried to fix it using break statement. It somehow worked. But still not getting result as expected.

The code written in python3.2 is:-

```
list=[]
item=""
while item!='DONE':
    item=input("Enter the number, To discontinue enter 'DONE': ")

    if item.isdigit():
        item=int(item)
        list.append(item)
    else:
        list.append(item)

del list[-1]
print("The list is: ",list)

num=int(input("Enter the number you want to search in list: "))
def search(list,num):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i]==num:
            print("Item found")
            break
        else:
            print("Not found")
    return
search(list,num)
```

Please suggest how I can modify it to search both "integer" as well as "string" type elements. My code is working fine for integer type element.

Comment: Why don't  you want to use `in`?

Comment: I am trying to look for an alternate option as It is my learning phase in python.

Comment: `list.index(element)` will return the index of the first element it found in the list, raises `ValueError` otherwise. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: No, Actually I am trying to check that whether an element is present in list or not?

Comment: Since you are beginning, I should suggest that you not use `list` as a variable name, since the built-in function `list` will be masked and that can be a dangerous habit. Also, when you ask a question, you should always try to post expected results, and the results you are getting, especially if you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert the string to an `int` when you do this:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number you want to search in list: "))
```

When the input isn't a number, this will throw an exception.

Instead, why don't you just do the same thing you did in the first part of your code using `isdigit()`? If it's a number, cast it to an `int`, and if it's not a number, leave it as a string. Then your code should work for non-numbers too.

```
num = input("Enter the number you want to search in list: ")
if num.isdigit():
    num = int(num)
```

---

*Alternatively*, a second solution would be not to cast anything to `int` in either the first or second part of your code. So in other words, keep everything as strings, i.e.

```
while item != 'DONE':
    item = input("Enter the number, To discontinue enter 'DONE': ")
    list.append(item)

...

num = input("Enter the number you want to search in list: ")
```

Comment: Right, there is no need to check types here.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky No it didn't... I tried this code but NOT worked for integers, (working well for strings). Don't know what I am missing here??? :-list=[12,45,63,"asd",458,1,"sdr",104]
print(list)
item=input("Enter the item you want to search in list: ")
def search(list,item):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i]==item:
            print("Item found")
            break
        else:
            print("Not found")
    return
search(list,item)

Comment: Right, you have to either cast to `int` in both parts of your code, or you have to cast to `int` in neither part of your code. Did you try making the substitution I did above?

Comment: @AmritanshuVerma In the code you posted in your comment, your list contains both `int`s and strings. If they contained strings only as in `["12", "45", "63", "asd", "458", "1", "sdr", "104"]`, you'd be fine with no type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
def seach(l, elm):
    try:
        l.index(elm)
        print "found"
    except:
        print "not found"
```

It is way more pythonic than a custom loop.

PS : As you are in your learning phase, do not try to find way to perform a task. The 'in' keyword is made for it.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to differentiate between integers and strings — they're both just *values* that Python can handle the same way to do what you want **in this case**. Given that fact, you could rewrite your code along the following lines (which includes several other techniques you could use to simplify the logic and organize your code in a more standard way — see [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

```
def search(a_list, value):
    for item in a_list:  # note: no need to use an index to iterate a list
        if item == value:
            print("Value found")
            break
    else:  # only executes if loop finishes without break
        print("Value not found")

my_list = []  # note: avoid using the names of built-ins like "list"
while True:
    value = input("Enter an value, to discontinue enter 'DONE': ")
    if value == 'DONE':
        break
    my_list.append(value)

print("The list is: ", my_list)

value = int(input("Enter the value you want to search for in the list: "))
search(my_list, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a learning exercise, I'll submit this as a search avoiding `in`.  Others will claim it is a dirty rotten cheat.  Why?

```
def search(inlist, item):
    print(item, end="")
    if inlist.__contains__(item):
        print(" found")
    else:
        print(" not found")

mylist = []
item = None
while item != 'DONE':
    item = input("Enter the number, To discontinue enter 'DONE': ")
    mylist.append(item)

while True:
    num = input("Enter the item you want to search for: ")
    search(mylist, num)
```

.
.

Also in the spirit of learning, here is a solution which uses a set.  We probably would not bother creating a list in the first place if we were using a set, but let's assume the list came from elsewhere.

The point here is that if you had a large list and a very large number of searches then using a set will probably be faster than iterating through the list.

```
def search(inset, item):
    print(item, end="")

    if inset & set((item,)):
        print(" found")
    else:
        print(" not found")

mylist = []
item = None
while item != 'DONE':
    item = input("Enter the number, To discontinue enter 'DONE': ")
    mylist.append(item)

myset = set(mylist)
while True:
    num = input("Enter the item you want to search for: ")
    search(myset, num)
```